# I'm having problems to deploy front end app in netlify or vercel

Tags: reactjs, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a front end react app in Netlify but im reciving an error. Look:

```
8:10:39 AM: Failed to compile.
8:10:39 AM: 
8:10:39 AM: src/App.tsx                                                             no-unused-vars
8:10:39 AM:   Line 31:21:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
8:10:39 AM:   Line 46:25:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
8:10:39 AM: src/components/Countdown.jsx
8:10:39 AM: src/components/LevelUpModal.jsx
8:10:39 AM:   Line 16:17:  img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images  jsx-a11y/alt-text
8:10:39 AM: src/contexts/ChallengesContext.jsx
8:10:39 AM:   Line 3:9:  'reactLocalStorage' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars
8:10:39 AM: src/contexts/CountDownContext.jsx                                                                                  eqeqeq
8:10:39 AM:   Line 40:8:   React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'startNewChallenge'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! errno 1
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! moveittypescript@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! Exit status 1
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR!
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! Failed at the moveittypescript@0.1.0 build script.
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
8:10:39 AM: npm ERR!     /opt/buildhome/.npm/_logs/2021-03-01T11_10_39_060Z-debug.log
8:10:39 AM: ​
8:10:39 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:10:39 AM:   "build.command" failed                                        
8:10:39 AM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
8:10:39 AM: ​
8:10:39 AM:   Error message
8:10:39 AM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build
8:10:39 AM: ​
8:10:39 AM:   Error location
8:10:39 AM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
8:10:39 AM:   npm run build
8:10:39 AM: ​
8:10:39 AM:   Resolved config
8:10:39 AM:   build:
8:10:39 AM:     command: npm run build
8:10:39 AM:     commandOrigin: ui
8:10:39 AM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/build
```

I already try deploy in Vercel to but i recive the same errors. Could be the warnings a deployu problem?

Comment: deploy problems*

Comment: in vercel too but...*

Comment: Did you know you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66421283/edit)?  Comments are meant for asking about the question, or replying to other comments.  But thanks for fixing those mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

1. img elements must have an alt prop : Use alt attribute for images
   which are required for react.
2. 'reactLocalStorage' is defined but never used is just a warning no
   issues on it.
3. React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: Check its syntax or
   check import.